# Delhi/Android Compile Error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'requestLegacyExternalStorage' in package 'android'

Tags: android, delphi

I'm using Embarcadero's Delphi 10.4 and trying to create an app deployed to an Amazon Fire which is using Android's 9 (API level 28) OS. No matter what I try, every time I try and run the project, I get an error reading "No resource identifier found for attribute 'requestLegacyExternalStorage' in package 'android'".

My Build.Gradle file is targeting the OS's API level. I did try setting both the compile and target SDK versions to 29 though to see if it made a difference.

```
...
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake.arguments '-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang',
                            '-DANDROID_STL=c++_static',
                            '-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-22'
        }
    }
...
```

My AndroidManifest is targeting my API level but again I tried 29 as well. I've also tried setting the 'requestLegacyExternalStorage' attribute to true and false. If I delete the attribute from the manifest then it'll successfully compile but then the second the splash screen appears on my device, the connection crashes in my IDE with no errors reported and the splash screen stays on my device screen... I can set a breakpoint and see that the Application.Initialize never even executes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- BEGIN_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.embarcadero.WhsScanner"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0.0"
        android:installLocation="auto">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" android:targetSdkVersion="29" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="True"/>
    <application android:persistent="False" 
        android:restoreAnyVersion="False" 
        android:label="WhsScanner" 
        android:debuggable="True" 
        android:largeHeap="False"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:resizeableActivity="false"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="false">
        
        <!-- Our activity is a subclass of the built-in NativeActivity framework class.
             This will take care of integrating with our NDK code. -->
        <activity android:name="com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity"
                android:label="WhsScanner"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
                android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <!-- Tell NativeActivity the name of our .so -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="WhsScanner" />
            <intent-filter>  
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity>
        
        <receiver android:name="com.embarcadero.rtl.notifications.NotificationAlarm" />

    </application>
</manifest>
<!-- END_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
```

The SDK elements I'm using are as follows... Should all be up to date.

- Android SDK Tools rev 25.2.5
- Android SDK Platform-tools  rev 29.0.6
- Android SDK Build Tools rev 29.0.3

and then, of course, I have all SDK properties pointing to the API level 28 configuration files.

I can't even create a blank application!! PLEASE HELP!

Comment: `requestLegacyExternalStorage` is not available in API level 28, it was introduced in level 29.

Comment: Is the blank app exhibiting the same problem? Does a blank app work on any other devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the same problem in this way:

1. project compile and building.
2. find AndroidManifest.xml in my project build-out folder
3. move to my project source folder
4. modify AndroidManifest.xml with notepad to remove
   remove android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="false"
5. Rad studio menu Project -> Deployment
6. uncheck original AndroidManifest.xml
7. add AndroidManifest.xml from Project Source Folder( step #3,4 file )
8. Save Project

Compile and Building...

(addition)
you don't need to copy and modify, deply changing  AndroidManifest.xml from Build folder. Modify AndroidManifest.template.xml in your source folder. compile and build your source. that's all.
I think this process is more simple.